Dependency 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct:1.4.1.Final' not found Inspection info: Reports resolution problems in a Maven model
I'm trying to use MapStruct to convert DTOs to entities in my Spring Boot project. I added the MapStruct dependency to my pom.xml file as follows:
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
    <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
    <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
</dependency>

However, I heard that MapStruct might be deprecated in the latest versions of Spring Boot. Is this true? If so, what alternatives should I consider?
Additionally, I want to avoid manually mapping each field between DTOs and entities like this:
User userDtoToUser(UserDto userDto) {
    User user = new User();
    user.setName(userDto.getName());
    user.setEmail(userDto.getEmail());
    // Mapping other fields...
    return user;
}

Is there a better way to handle the mapping without writing boilerplate code for each field?
Thanks for your help!
